# I need to automate solver in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-solver

I'm not well-versed in VBA so I have some questions. I have a solver set up, that runs smoothly. However, I would like to automate it. I basically need to run it 2,000 times. The constraints reference the row number as well, so I need to constraints to automatically go down one row each time. My objective value varies... but if there's a way to reference the value based on the cell, that would be incredible. Is there anyway to change that since each row has a different number?

Code below. Thank you!!!

```
Sub Macro4()
'
Dim i As Integer

' Macro4 Macro
' atempt 3

For i = 1 To 100

    SolverReset
    SolverOk SetCell:="$U$7" & i, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=152, ByChange:="$G$7:$J$7" & i, _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$K$7" & i, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$G$7" & i
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$7" & i, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$O$7" & i
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$L$7" & i, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$H$7" & i
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$H$7" & i, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$P$7" & i
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$M$7" & i, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$I$7" & i
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$I$7" & i, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$Q$7" & i
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$N$7" & i, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$J$7" & i
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$J$7" & i, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$R$7" & i
    SolverSolve

End

Next i
    
End Sub
```

I tried executing this and it pretty much did nothin. No errors. However, nothing in excel changed...

Comment: Think about what `SetCell:="$U$7" & i` will result in.  Hint: it won't increment the 7

Comment: Also, you don't want the [`End`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/end-statement)

Comment: I'm still not sure what that means... How would I make the row change each time? Thanks for the help!

Comment: `SetCell:="$U$7" & i` should be `SetCell:="U" & i` ($ is superfluous here) etc for the other references

Comment: Loop `For i=7 To 106` or 8 To 107 whatever you mean.